# Different intervals in an ordered vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, model-theory, ordered-fields

Consider an ordered vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ in the usual language of ordered vector spaces $(<,0,-,+,\lambda\cdot)_{\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}}$. For the duration of this question, the word *interval* refers to a *non-degenerate bounded open interval* within such a vector space.

Call two intervals $(a,b) \subseteq V$ and $(c,d) \subseteq V$ *definably isomorphic* if we can find an invertible function definable with parameters from $V$ that maps $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$.

One can easily construct an ordered vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ containing two intervals that are not definably isomorphic to each other. For example, take the lexicographic product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}$, and compare the uncountable interval between the vectors $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ to the countable interval between the vectors $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$. The two intervals in this example are not equinumerous in the first place: one cannot even have a bijection between them, much less a definable isomorphism.

**Question: What's a good example of an ordered vector space structure over $\mathbb{Q}$ containing two equinumerous, but not definably isomorphic intervals? Preferably one that can be presented / explained easily to non-logicians (e.g. ideally not a Henkin construction).**

---

Note: It follows from the usual o-minimality results that such an isomorphism is piecewise affine, with finitely many pieces. One can have a definable isomorphism between two intervals even if one cannot have an affine isomorphism. For example, consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as an ordered vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. The intervals $(0,\sqrt{2})$ and $(0,1)$ have no affine isomorphism between them since $\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, but one can still write down a piecewise affine definable isomorphism $f$ between the two intervals as follows.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  x  & \text{ if } x \in (0,2-\sqrt{2})\\
  \frac{1}{2}(x - 2 + \sqrt{2}) + 2 - \sqrt{2} & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Aren't any two open intervals in an ordered field isomorphic by an affine map?  Just take the unique affine map that matches up their endpoints.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Sure, but we only have an ordered vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ here, not an ordered field.  We cannot multiply arbitrary elements of our space, only by rational scalars. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You wrote "ordered field" in the bolded question.

Comment: Oops :) Thanks for pointing this our, edited so the bolded question should now match the rest of the text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Q}^2$ ordered lexicographically, the intervals $((0,0),(0,1))$ and $((0,0),(1,0))$ are both countable, but there is no piecewise affine bijection between them (where piecewise means "with finitely many pieces").

To see this, suppose we have an affine map $A$ given by $$(x,y)\mapsto q(x,y)+(a,b) = (qx+a,qy+b).$$ Then for all $y$, $A(0,y) = (a,qy+b)$, so the first coordinate of the output of $A$ is constant on the entire interval $((0,0),(0,1))$. So a piecewise affine map (with finitely many pieces) only takes on finitely many first-coordinate output values on the interval $((0,0),(0,1))$, and thus it cannot be surjective onto $((0,0),(1,0))$.